# Coding Academy 2015 magazine - PHP Unexpected T_String

Tags: php

I am currently learning PHP in the Coding Academy 2015 magazine. The tutorial was all going well until I came across the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'check_for_race' (T_STRING) in 
>   /home/u345668349/public_html/warddesign2/f1calendar.php on line 13

The full HTML/PHP code up to now is as follows:

```
<?php

$race_data = FALSE;

$races = array( 
'australia' => array('title' => 'australian', 'location' => 'Melbourne',        
'date' => '13/3/2015'),
'malaysia' => array('title' => 'Malaysia','location' => 'Kuala Lumpur',     
'date' => '27/3/2015'),
'china' => array('title' => 'Chinese',  'location' => 'Shanghai', 'date'     
=> '10/4/2015'),
'bahrain' => array('title' => 'Bahrain',    'location' => 'Sakhir',    
'date' => '17/4/2015'),
'spain' => array('title' => 'Spanish', 'location' => 'catalunya', 'date'    
=> '08/5/2015'),
);

if(isset($_POST['location']) check_for_race($_POST['location']);

function check_for_race($location){
global $races, $race_data;

$location = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'location', FILTER_SANITIZE_STIRNG,       
FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);

if(isset($races[$location]))
$race_data = $races[$location];
else $race_data = 'No matching races found';
return; 
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>

<form method="post">
<fieldset>
<label for="location">Choose a race:</label>
<select name="location">
<?php foreach($races as $location => $race): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $location; ?>"><?php echo $location;?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View">
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

It does not seem to like the line 13, written below:

```
if(isset($_POST['location']) check_for_race($_POST['location']);
```

If anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated. I've been through the book and the code several times, even changing the order of it but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This is a great argument in favour of using curly braces, as reading your code is hard. And you might have spotted the missing parenthesis if you have braces to *break up* you code.  Each to their own, of course..

Comment: Often, when you get a `T_STRING` error, it is on the line right before the line given.

Comment: @James I agree.  I use them even for my one-line statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis:

```
if(isset($_POST['location']) check_for_race($_POST['location']);
```

Should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['location'])) check_for_race($_POST['location']);
                    //      ^---- notice this
```

It might be better to get into the habit of using curly brackets with your `if()` statements and loops. It makes debugging such as this so much easier:

```
if( isset($_POST['location']) )
{
    check_for_race( $_POST['location'] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks BenM. That worked great, your help is much appreciated. Unfortunately this is how its written in my magazine. Now I have another error, but I'll put that on a different post. Cheers

Comment: @wardheed No problem. I've just updated the answer with more information on how you can use curly brackets.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah that makes it easier to check through. Many Thanks